# Text matcher on javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need some JS library, which could match category by long text request.

For example, I have categories `Apples`, `Red Apples`, `Green Apples`, `Oranges` and request `Red Juicy Apple 1 Kilo from Spain`. In this case the category should be `Red Apples`. So, simple loop and `contains()` is not enough.

I've searched some libs like https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural, but classification not suitable because in my case I do not know all possible requests and could not train it.

Maybe I need to stem request, calculate words distances request to categories and sort it?

Please help me with this anti-full-text-search.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305000/javascript-fuzzy-search-that-makes-sense/

Answer (score 1):

A very rudimentary way, but it meets your single provided example:

```
var categories = [ "Apples", "Red Apples", "Green Apples", "Oranges" ];
var intputString = "Red Juicy Apple 1 Kilo from Spain";

var words = inputString.split(' ');

for (int wordIndex = 0; wordIndex < words.length; wordIndex++) {
  for (int categoryIndex = 0; categoryIndex < categories.length; categoryIndex++) {
    if (categories[categoryIndex].indexOf(words[wordIndex]) > -1) {
      // The word words[wordIndex] is in the string categories[categoryIndex]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it is still loop with contains. I just have found lib http://glench.github.io/fuzzyset.js/ which I hope will help me. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @user2298956 Yes, your answer is much better than mine!

Answer (score 1):

I have found http://glench.github.io/fuzzyset.js/ and it seems to work.

```
>>f = FuzzySet(['Apples', 'Red Apples', 'Green Apples', 'Oranges'])
>>f.get("Red Juicy Apple 1 Kilo from Spain")

[Array[2]0: 0.3030303030303031: "Red Apples"length: 2__proto__: Array[0]]
```

Hope it suppose not only English....

Comment: This is better than my answer!