# How to make fuzzy search using Lodash java-script library?

Tags: javascript, lodash, fuzzy-search

I want to make fuzzy search from array of objects using query string .
Search may be nested in search object like the following example ;

```js
var data = [ 
              {
                "id":"1",
                "name":"Ali",
                "BOD":"29/10/2055",
                "type":"primary",
                "email":"b@v.com",
                "mobile":"0100000000",
                "notes":["note1" ,"note2" ,"note3"]
              },
               {
                "id":"2",
                "name":"Tie",
                "BOD":"29/10/2055",
                "type":"primary",
                "email":"b@v.net",
                "mobile":"0100000000",
                "notes":["note4" ,"note5" ,"note6"]
              }
  ];


   function search(query){
     // search code go here
     
     }

   // search examples
   search('.net'); //expected data[1]
   search('ali');  //expected data[0]
   search('0110'); //expected data[0],data[1]
```

Comment: why do you get two results for `'ali'`?

Comment: What do you mean by "fuzzy search"? Do you want `query` to be matched against any of the object values?

Comment: What is logic for returning matches? See also [Javascript fuzzy search that makes sense](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305000/javascript-fuzzy-search-that-makes-sense)

Comment: @guest271314 that is more in-line with my expectation of what a fuzzy search would do.

Comment: @NinaScholz sorry i fixed it now

Comment: @vlaz yes fuzzy search is query to be matched against any of the object values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made simple solution it is not that optimal but it works .
this done without score of fuzzy search for nested searching .

```js
var data = [ 
              {
                "id":"1",
                "name":"Ali",
                "BOD":"29/10/2055",
                "type":"primary",
                "email":null,
                "mobile":"010100000000",
                "notes":["note1" ,"note2.nett" ,"note3"]
              },
               {
                "id":"2",
                "name":"Tie",
                "BOD":"29/10/2055",
                "type":"primary",
                "email":"b@v.net",
                "mobile":"0100000000",
                "notes":["note4" ,"note5" ,"note6"]
              }
  ];

    /**
     * query: query string to match with
     * dataArray: data array variable, array or opject to search it
     **/
   function search(query,dataArray){
     // search code go here
     //console.log(query);
     var matched = [];
     //init null values
     if(!dataArray)dataArray={};
     if(!query)query='';
     dataArray.forEach(function(obj,index){
        for(var key in obj){
          if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(key) || !obj[key]) continue;
          if(obj[key].toString().indexOf(query) !== -1)
            {
              matched.push(obj );
            } 
        }
     });
     return matched ;      
     }

   // search examples .
  console.log("found",search('.net',data).length);//expected data[0] data[1]
  console.log("found",search('Ali',data).length);//expected data[0]
  console.log("found",search('0116',data).length);//expected data[0],data[1]
```