# How to select and replace certain words in input strings regardless of the full string?

Tags: javascript, filter, chat

I am making a filter for a chat room I own.

 
I was successful in having it turn NSFW words into a bunch of symbols and asterisks to censor it, but many people bypass it by simply putting a backslash, period, or other symbol/letter after it because I only put in the words without the punctuation and symbols. They also add characters too such as eeeNSFWeee so the filter doesn't count it as a word.

 
Is there a way to make it so that the filter will select certain characters that form a word in a string and replace them (with or without replacing the extra characters connected to the message)?

 
The filter is made in JavaScript and Socket.io

 
Filter code:

```
    const array = [
  "NSFW",
  "Bad Word"
  "Inappropriate Word"
];

message = message
  .split(" ")
  .map((word) => (array.includes(word.toLowerCase()) ? "$#!%" : word))
  .join(" ");
```

For example, if somebody typed "Bad Word" exactly like that (caps are not a problem), it would censor it successfully. However, if somebody typed "Bad Word." that would be a problem because since it has a period it would count it as a different word, that's what I need fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of approaches you could take here.

You could use replace() if you just want to remove symbols. For example:

```
word.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.`'"!;\^:*?<>{}_\[\]]/g, '')
```

You could use [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) in general, which allows you to match on patterns instead of exact string matching.

You could also use more complex fuzzy matching libraries or custom fuzzy matching to accomplish your goal. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305000/javascript-fuzzy-search-that-makes-sense) may be helpful.

Comment: Can you use a variable attached to an array to specify a substring using the string.prototype.replace method in the Regular Expressions?

Comment: You could, but you could also use an "or" operator in regex instead. For example: `const badWords = /NSFW|Bad Word|Innapropiate Word/gi const censoredMessage = message.replace(badWords, '$#!%')`

Comment: I messed around with it a bunch and it works! Thankyou so much